# How to do progressive springboot build with cached steps in docker

Tags: spring-boot, docker, maven

I am trying to build [this](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaweb-employee-rostering) springboot project inside a docker container. The build takes too long and downloads too many packages to for me to be able to wait until it finishes. I have been trying to follow pratices applied in npm and others where you first download depedencies then do the actual build in separate steps.

Something like:

```
COPY pom.xml /src/
COPY project1/pom.xml /src/project1/

RUN mvn dependency:resolve dependency:go-offline

COPY . .
RUN mvn install --off-line
```

I just cannot make it work. The install step is always failing because of missing packages.

Any ideas or guides on how to do this.

Comment: `dependency:go-offline` downloads most of the dependencies but not all (adding `mvn dependency:resolve-plugins` appears to solve this). So you will need to remove the `--off-line` (I believe some plugins or plugin dependencies aren't download). Also instead of `mvn install` use `mvn package` as I suspect you don't need to install it in a local repository. Also I would strongly suggest using a multi-stage build to reduce the final container size. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MDEP-82 and http://whitfin.io/speeding-up-maven-docker-builds/

Comment: Did it!! It worked as you said. It's impossible to download everything with the dependency:* goals, but at least I had more than 90% reduced build time. I think I will add some proxy for caching next.

Yep, the multistage was part of the plan.

Thanks a LOT!!!